# Declaring Object of one class into another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have class named Building :

```
@interface Building : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString* node;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString* subnode;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString* supernode;
@property (nonatomic,retain)Node *reference;
@end
```

I have another class named:Node

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray* strArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString * strName;
```

I declared instance of Building from third class .I have set strName from third class by using the reference of the building:

```
   building.reference.strName=strVal;
```

But this giving me null value .How can i set this value by using the reference of the Building class.

Comment: Are you actually _creating_ a `Building` instance, then setting its `reference` to a `Node` that you've likewise created?

Comment: Also, are you sure that strVal is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are initialising `reference` in `Building`'s `-init` method. For example (assuming `Node` also inherits directly from `NSObject`):

```
- (id) init {
    self.reference = [[Node alloc] init];
    return self;
}
```

In addition you could write a designated initialiser method to pass in an existing Node when initialising, e.g. `-initWithNode: (Node)myNode`. Then you would get your `Building`'s `-init` method to call `[self initWithNode:[[Node alloc] init]`.

Then to initialise a `Building` object, you can call `[[Building alloc] init]` (to get a Building with a blank Node) or `[[Building alloc] initWithNode:myNodeObject]` (to get a Building with a Node you already instantiated).

Note that if Node doesn't inherit directly from NSObject (which doesn't do anything in it's own `init`), you should call the superclass `init` routine as well, so your initialiser would become:

```
- (id) init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self.reference = [[Node alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```